# Open ports to Docker containers

Tags: ubuntu, networking, docker

I'm starting with docker, just triying to run a Docker container with a web aplication and trying to see it in our local network.

I have installed a fresh Ubuntu 14 LTS in VirtualBox, without any extra services (no GUI, no LAMP, no OpenSSH...), and then installed only Docker:

```
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

and I have run an Odoo (OpenERP) container (previusly run postgree container)

```
docker run -d -e POSTGRES_USER=odoo -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo --name db postgres
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:8069:8069 --name odoo --link db:db -t odoo
```

Very simple. It looks like it is working. I have not installed browser, but I connected via telnet to 127.0.0.1:8069 and sent GET request. It answered.

Now I need to access the service from outside. How?

- > VirtualBox network interface is configured as bridge.
- > I have set a fixed IP (192.168.0.150) in Ubuntu eth0 interface.
- > UFW is disabled
- > I can ping to 192.168.0.150 form other computers, and ubuntu answers.
- > But browser doesnt detect anything at 192.168.0.150:8069
- > Can't connect via telnet to 192.168.0.150:8069

I suppose it must be some configuration of port redirection or interface mapping. Could you help me, please? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the answer. Problem was the port assignement. If you set:

```
-p 127.0.0.1:8069:8069
```

you are exposing ONLY localhost. This is great security option if you need only a local service, and want to access it only from the server. But, if you want to expose the port to ALL interfaces, just type:

```
-p 8069:8069
```

Then, you can access the service through the network via eth0 interface :)

Comment: After finding this answer and accodring to oddoargentina the correct command to be able to access container from the outside world is sudo docker run -d --link aeroo_docs:aeroo -p 8069:8069 -p 8072:8072 -v /odoo80/config:/etc/odoo -v /odoo80/sources:/mnt/extra-addons -v /odoo80/data_dir:/var/lib/odoo --link db-odoo80:db --restart=always --name odoo80 adhoc/odoo-adhoc:8.0